# CMake: add compiler flags to a target if another specific target depends on it

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm struggling with the following problem: I want to add some compiler flags to a target depending upon whether another specific target is being built. With make this problem seems to be possible to solve via target-specific variables, but how do you dot that with cmake?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't related to C, just to CMake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMake you **cannot** set compiler flags depending on what is being built.

All flags are determined on *configuration stage (`cmake` invocation), but selecting targets for build is performed only on *build stage* (`make` invocation).

---

While build-dependent flags are supported by `make`, they are not supported by many of other build tools. And CMake tends to be build tool-independent.